# OpenSSL Ed25519 C-code example to verify a signed message

Tags: encryption, openssl, digital-signature, ed25519

The link here, https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/Ed25519.html, contains C-code that works just perfect to sign a message using Ed25519 in a C/C++ program.
But I just can't find any corresponding code to verify a signed message.

Anyone knows examples of c-code (or C++) that actually performs a verification, i.e. a do_verify(...) analogue to the do_sign(...) in the link above?

Edit: I managed to add a code suggestion, however I really don't know if I got everything right. That is pretty important when you want to verify a signed message... Anyone knows if there is something wrong with the code below?

```
int do_verify(EVP_PKEY* pkey,
    const unsigned char* sig, size_t sig_len,
    const unsigned char* msg, size_t msg_len) {
    EVP_MD_CTX* md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    int ret = EVP_DigestVerifyInit(md_ctx, NULL, NULL, NULL, pkey) &&
        EVP_DigestVerify(md_ctx, sig, sig_len, msg, msg_len) == 1;
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(md_ctx);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Uh, yes, when you copy the init parameters and get a correct verification then it succeeded. Where is your doubt?

Comment: Thanks! Since I could not find a reference implementation of this and it is the first time I have tried to guess how it should be performed I'm not entirely sure it's accurate. What if I missed one parameter or flag that can render the validation unsusable given some condition?